# Proving Distributions

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that the following is a distribution:

X ^ ( Y => Z)

Where ^ is the and operator, and => is implies.

I figure its gonna look something like this, but I can't prove it using any known theorems:

X ^ ( Y => Z) = (X ^ Y) => (X ^ Z)

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prove this because it is not true.

Suppose X = False then:

- original formula is always false

  X ∧ (Y ⇒ Z) ≡ False ∧ (Y ⇒ Z) ≡ False
- but after distributing `and` over `implication` it is always true

  (X ∧ Y) ⇒ (X ∧ Z) ≡ (False ⇒ False) ≡ True

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I understand what you have just said, and it makes sense to me. But is there any way to prove this using previously known theorems ? But thanks for your help !

Comment: Single counterexample is enough to prove that conjunction *does not* distribute over implication, so you don't need to refer to any other theorems.